# What does a question mark `?` in the STAT column of `ps` on MacOS indicate?

Tags: macos, command-line

When running the command

```
ps -xo pid,stat,user,time
```

On MacOS (Monterey; version 12.5), I sometimes get a `?` in the `STAT` column:

```
  PID STAT USER        TIME
[...] Removed for brevity
72633 S    mbercx   0:00.06
72949 ?s   mbercx   0:00.00
72952 ?    mbercx   0:00.00
74045 S    mbercx  56:17.38
```

What does it mean to have a `?` in the STAT column, i.e. the process state?

Comment: This would be he BSD process state code.  Unfortunately, at present, I can’t find anything that describes the question mark.

Comment: Are you running the default macOS version of `ps` here?

Comment: @nohillside yes, I have made no modifications as far as I know. I'm also not the only one to have run into these `?` states, see https://github.com/aiidateam/aiida-core/issues/3107

Comment: It's unclear whether this is about macOS though.

Comment: Apologies, I discussed with the team members who encountered this, and both were using macOS. I've also never encountered this issue on e.g. Ubuntu, whereas I can reliably reproduce it on my macbook pro and mac mini.

Answer (score 8):

It means Unknown state. (which basically should not happen)

Looking at the source code that nohillside pointed to and in other files https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/adv_cmds/blob/7c10d3f757148b048a743f7d1d71be0153b2381f/ps/print.c#L441

The ? comes from [this line in tasks.c](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/adv_cmds/blob/60bc9ebf1df7e0a3d8500ecd7e4dd1e008765af5/ps/tasks.c#L48) together with a comment on how they match the numeric status.

```
                            /*01234567 */
char    mach_state_table[] = " RUSITH?";
```

From other googling https://github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/1886#issuecomment-191455988

I see a list of the eight states as

> 0   Zombie
> 1   Running
> 2   Stuck
> 3   Sleeping
> 4   Idle
> 5   Stopped
> 6   Halted
> 7   Unknown

The names here seem to match the letters in the ps code.

See [@pwncat's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460395/237) for a more complete listing from Apple's code in that case from top.

man ps does not include the Halted and Unknown states.
Nor does the [xnu code for macos 13](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/5c2921b07a2480ab43ec66f5b9e41cb872bc554f/bsd/sys/proc.h#L159)

Older versions did include a D status from manuals but the OSX 10.0 code has the same constants as current macOS.

Answer (score 6):

On macOS, `ps` is roughly based on the `libtop.c` library whose [source](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/top/blob/a989bd5d18246e330e5feadd80958b913351f8ae/libtop.c#L602) contains the following function (white-space truncated):

```c
/* Return a pointer to a string representation of a process state. */
const char * libtop_state_str(uint32_t state) {
    const char *strings[] = {
        "zombie",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_ZOMBIE 0
        "running",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_RUN    1
        "stuck",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_STUCK  2
        "sleeping",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_SLEEP  3
        "idle",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_IDLE   4
        "stopped",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_STOP   5
        "halted",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_HALT   6
        "unknown"
#define LIBTOP_STATE_UNKNOWN    7
    };
    assert(LIBTOP_NSTATES == sizeof(strings) / sizeof(char *));
    assert(state <= LIBTOP_STATE_MAX);
    assert(LIBTOP_STATE_MAXLEN >= 8); /* "sleeping" */
    return strings[state];
}
```

As correctly pointed out in another answer, `ps`'s [`print.c`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/adv_cmds/blob/60bc9ebf1df7e0a3d8500ecd7e4dd1e008765af5/ps/print.c#L450) takes process state symbols from [`tasks.c`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/adv_cmds/blob/60bc9ebf1df7e0a3d8500ecd7e4dd1e008765af5/ps/tasks.c#L48) where they directly coincide with the state offsets found in `libtop.c` as shown above.

The last one is unknown, meaning the process state does not fall into any particular category. And the last symbol is a question mark, thus in rare cases you may see it in the `STAT` column.

Comment: The question here is about the "STAT" column, not the "TTY" column.

Comment: I'm aware and am taking an educated guess as this is undocumented. Despite correlation≠causation, the presence of `?` in both TTY and STAT is worth looking into.

Comment: Just remove the portion with the irrelevant TTY states and you’ll be good.

Comment: The top repo https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/top shows no chnage in later versions - more complex command have their own repo in Apple's release of OSS code.

Comment: @mmmmmm Indeed, I mentioned "not much has changed" but pointed to the wrong repo. I'll correct that, thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

It means that the `ps` command doesn't match the operating system.

The inclusion of a question mark in the `state` column by the BSD `ps` command is the result of hitting [a `default:` case in the code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/bin/ps/print.c#L262) where the current process state as reported by the operating system is not one of the states that the code of `ps` actually understands.

MacOS doesn't use a straight vanilla BSD kernel.
Some commands have been modified to work with the kernel differences.
Clearly, a modification was missed here.

Comment: macOS doesn't include the FreeBSD version of `ps`, its `ps` has a different `state()` function (see https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/adv_cmds/blob/7c10d3f757148b048a743f7d1d71be0153b2381f/ps/print.c#L441).

Comment: Actually, it's much the same.  If you look more carefully, you'll spot that in the `default:` case the end of the string, for an unknown state that the code doesn't understand, as returned by a state translation function, is a question mark character.

Comment: `*cp = mach_state_table[k->state];` assumes quite a lot about the value of `k->state` though.

Comment: Again: if you look more carefully, you'll find that the state translation function provides all of the values of that field, including the value for when the code doesn't understand a state.